# Web Audio API -- Capture Stream from Analyser

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

The Web Audio API examples show a source stream going directly to an audio context destination node, like the speakers or canvas. I want to collect data from the analyser, and then render a React component with it. The best I came up with is to interval poll:

```
const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

// start button click
mediaRecorder.start();
analyserPoll = setInterval(() => {
  analyser.getFloatTimeDomainData(buffer);
  collect = [...collect, buffer];
}, 500);

// stop button click
mediaRecorder.stop();
clearInterval(analyserPoll);
```

Is there a more official way of doing this inside the API without the setTimeout? For instance, saving to a Blob or file, and then running my analyser code on that? It's a McLeod pitch detector.

Comment: Don't know of a "more official" way of doing this, but your method is not going to work.  The polling of the AnalyserNode isn't really synchronized with the audio context, so you will either end up with duplicated samples or with gaps.

Comment: What if I poll with MediaRecorder.requestData(), and collect in an ondataavailable event?

Comment: That doesn't help.  Events are async, and the audio thread just keeps running so some random amount of time has passed between when you thought it would get called to when it actually gets called so you end up with the same problem.  The solution might be to use a MediaStreamDestinationNode to capture the audio and use that as the source stream for a MediaRecorder.  I haven't actually tried any of these, so I don't know for sure.

Comment: How about an AudioWorklet, which passes the Float32Array input channel to a WASM, and pushes the output of the WASM result into the worklet's class property? Then, when recording stops, it uses the ports to post a message back to the scope of the audio context?

Comment: That should work.  Not sure where the WASM part comes in since your example wasn't using WASM.  Plain JS should be more than fast enough to save the data away for later.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

AudioWorklets are not required. What's required is proper design of state and effects. Create an effectful action that set states for what you don't want to render, like a buffer:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // getFloatTimeDomainData
    // setBufferState
  }, //run effect when these deps change, buffer);
```

Then, after the audio api collection is over, like when the user hits a "Stop button" set the buffer to the data you want to render.

```
setData(buffer)
```

The effect won't render as you leave buffer alone. It's helpful when for expensive components and collecting data.

There are a ton of edge cases. User needs to gesture before audio api can be used. Audio Worklets are streams, so there's no real way to persist data. Sending messages on a port result in the same thing but more complicated.